# Mejorar archivo de busqueda en php / mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tengo una página de busqueda en una web personal. Me gustaría mejorar el código php para que el código no sea tan enrevesado, no se me ocurre como.

Alguien podría decirme como lo haría sin que haya tanto código y más fácil de gestionar.

Os dejo el código de la página. Le falta mucho código por que no me permite pegar todo. Espero os pueda servir de ayuda. Como veréis es ta hecho a base de condicionales

```
} elseif (($titulo !== "") && (empty($entidad)) && ($vivienda == "") && (!empty($descripcion)) && (empty($gasto)) && (empty($ingreso))) {
```

Que puede resultar farragoso.

Contiene una función al que envio el resultset y la query. Continene el html para construir la tabla.

Saludos,

```
       
        if (!isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_GET['sql'])) {
          require('../../conn/connection.php');
          $sql = $_GET['sql'];          
          $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);                
          
          busqueda($result,$sql);
        } 
        
        $query_total = "tabla_index, titulo, entidad, concat(cantidad,' €') cantidad, DATE_FORMAT(fecha,'%d/%m/%Y') as fecha1 , operacion, doc, renta, vivienda, inquilino,extra,extraPisos,descripcion";
        $query = '';

        
        
        if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {

          $sql ='';
          $result = '';

          //switch( $_POST['campo'] ) {
          //Caso de busqueda por título
          //case 'titulo':

            
          $titulo = $_POST['titulo'];
          $entidad =  $_POST['entidad'];
          $gasto = (isset($_POST['gasto'])) ? 1 : 0;
          $ingreso = (isset($_POST['ingreso'])) ? 1 : 0;
          $vivienda = $_POST['vivienda'];
          $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
          $fecha_inicial = $_POST['fecha_inicial'];
          $fecha_final = $_POST['fecha_final'];
          $sumar = (isset($_POST['sumar'])) ? 1 : 0;

          //Sin suma
          if (empty($sumar)) {
            if ((empty($_POST['fecha_inicial'])) && (empty($_POST['fecha_final']))) {

              if (($titulo !== "") && (empty($entidad)) && ($vivienda == "") && (empty($descripcion)) && (empty($gasto)) && (empty($ingreso))) {
                queryTipo('Titulo');
                $query = "Select {$query_total} from movimientos where titulo = '" . $titulo . "' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
              } elseif (($titulo == "") && (!empty($entidad)) && ($vivienda == "") && (empty($descripcion)) && (empty($gasto)) && (empty($ingreso))) {
                queryTipo('Entidad');
                $query = "Select {$query_total} from movimientos where entidad like '%" . $entidad . "%' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
              } elseif (($titulo == "") && (empty($entidad)) && ($vivienda !== "") && (empty($descripcion)) && (empty($gasto)) && (empty($ingreso))) {
                queryTipo('Vivienda');
                $query = "Select {$query_total} from movimientos where vivienda = '" . $vivienda . "' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
              } elseif (($titulo == "") && (empty($entidad)) && ($vivienda == "") && (!empty($descripcion)) && (empty($gasto)) && (empty($ingreso))) {
                queryTipo('Descripción');
                $query = "Select {$query_total} from movimientos where descripcion like '%" . $descripcion . "%' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
              } elseif (($titulo == "") && (empty($entidad)) && ($vivienda == "") && (empty($descripcion)) && (!empty($gasto)) && (empty($ingreso))) {
                queryTipo('Gastos');
                $query = "Select {$query_total} from movimientos where operacion = 'gasto' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
              } elseif (($titulo == "") && (empty($entidad)) && ($vivienda == "") && (empty($descripcion)) && (empty($gasto)) && (!empty($ingreso))) {
                queryTipo('Ingresos');
                $query = "Select {$query_total} from movimientos where operacion = 'ingreso' order by fecha desc;";

                //Titulo y entidad
              } elseif (($titulo !== "") && (!empty($entidad)) && ($vivienda == "") && (empty($descripcion)) && (empty($gasto)) && (empty($ingreso))) {
                queryTipo('Titulo y entidad');
                $query = "Select {$query_total} from movimientos where titulo = '" . $titulo . "' and entidad like '%" . $entidad . "%' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
                //Titulo y vivienda
         
               ...
              }
            } //Fin con fecha y sin sumar
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            busqueda($result,$query);
            //Inicio Con suma y sin fecha
          } else {
            if ((empty($_POST['fecha_inicial'])) && (empty($_POST['fecha_final']))) {

              if (($titulo !== "") && (empty($entidad)) && ($vivienda == "") && (empty($descripcion)) && (empty($gasto)) && (empty($ingreso))) {
                queryTipo('Sumar cantidad de Titulo');
                $query = "Select {$query_total} from movimientos where titulo = '" . $titulo . "' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
                $query_suma = "Select sum(cantidad) as cantidad from movimientos where titulo = '" . $titulo . "' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
              } elseif ...
                //Titulo y vivienda
              } elseif (($titulo !== "") && (empty($entidad)) && ($vivienda !== "") && (empty($descripcion)) && (empty($gasto)) && (empty($ingreso))) {
                queryTipo('Sumar cantidad de Titulo y vivienda');
                $query = "Select {$query_total} from movimientos where titulo = '" . $titulo . "' and vivienda = '" . $vivienda . "' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
                $query_suma = "Select sum(cantidad) as cantidad from movimientos where titulo = '" . $titulo . "' and vivienda = '" . $vivienda . "' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
                //Titulo y descripcion
              } elseif (($titulo !== "") && (empty($entidad)) && ($vivienda == "") && (!empty($descripcion)) && (empty($gasto)) && (empty($ingreso))) {
                queryTipo('Sumar cantidad de Titulo y descripcion');
                $query = "Select {$query_total} from movimientos where titulo = '" . $titulo . "' and descripcion like '%" . $descripcion . "%' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
                $query_suma = "Select sum(cantidad) as cantidad from movimientos where titulo = '" . $titulo . "' and descripcion like '%" . $descripcion . "%' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
                //Titulo, entidad y descripcion
              } elseif (($titulo !== "") && (!empty($entidad)) && ($vivienda == "") && (!empty($descripcion)) && (empty($gasto)) && (empty($ingreso))) {
                queryTipo('Sumar cantidad de Titulo, entidad y descripcion');
                $query = "Select {$query_total} from movimientos where titulo = '" . $titulo . "' and entidad like '%" . $entidad . "%' and descripcion like '%" . $descripcion . "%' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
                $query_suma = "Select sum(cantidad) as cantidad from movimientos where titulo = '" . $titulo . "' and entidad like '%" . $entidad . "%' and descripcion like '%" . $descripcion . "%' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
                //Titulo, entidad, vivienda y descripcion
              } elseif (($titulo !== "") && (!empty($entidad)) && ($vivienda !== "") && (!empty($descripcion)) && (empty($gasto)) && (empty($ingreso))) {
                queryTipo('Sumar cantidad de Titulo, entidad, vivienda y descripcion');
                $query = "Select {$query_total} from movimientos where titulo = '" . $titulo . "' and entidad like '%" . $entidad . "%' and vivienda = '" . $vivienda . "' and descripcion like '%" . $descripcion . "%' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
                $query_suma = "Select sum(cantidad) as cantidad from movimientos  where titulo = '" . $titulo . "' and entidad like '%" . $entidad . "%' and vivienda = '" . $vivienda . "' and descripcion like '%" . $descripcion . "%' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
                //Titulo y gasto
              } elseif (($titulo !== "") && (empty($entidad)) && ($vivienda == "") && (empty($descripcion)) && (!empty($gasto)) && (empty($ingreso))) {
                queryTipo('Sumar cantidad de Titulo y gasto');
                $query = "Select {$query_total} from movimientos where titulo = '" . $titulo . "' and operacion = 'gasto' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
                $query_suma = "Select sum(cantidad) as cantidad from movimientos where titulo = '" . $titulo . "' and operacion = 'gasto' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
                //Titulo y ingreso
              } elseif (($titulo !== "") && (empty($entidad)) && ($vivienda == "") && (empty($descripcion)) && (empty($gasto)) && (!empty($ingreso))) {
                queryTipo('Sumar cantidad de Titulo e ingreso');
                $query = "Select {$query_total} from movimientos where titulo = '" . $titulo . "' and operacion = 'ingreso' order by fecha desc;";
                $query_suma = "Select sum(cantidad) as cantidad from movimientos where titulo = '" . $titulo . "' and operacion = 'ingreso' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
                //entidad y vivienda
              } elseif (($titulo == "") && (!empty($entidad)) && ($vivienda !== "") && (empty($descripcion)) && (empty($gasto)) && (empty($ingreso))) {
                queryTipo('Sumar cantidad de Entidad y vivienda');
                $query = "Select {$query_total} from movimientos where entidad like '%" . $entidad . "%' and vivienda = '" . $vivienda . "' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";...
                //Titulo, entidad y descripcion
              } elseif (($titulo !== "") && (!empty($entidad)) && ($vivienda == "") && (!empty($descripcion)) && (empty($gasto)) && (empty($ingreso))) {
                queryTipo('Sumar cantidad de Titulo, entidad, descripcion y fechas');
                $query = "Select {$query_total} from movimientos where titulo = '" . $titulo . "' and entidad like '%" . $entidad . "%' and descripcion like '%" . $descripcion . "%' and fecha between '" . $fecha_inicial . "' and '" . $fecha_final . "' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
                $query_suma = "Select sum(cantidad) as cantidad from movimientos where titulo = '" . $titulo . "' and entidad like '%" . $entidad . "%' and descripcion like '%" . $descripcion . "%' and fecha between '" . $fecha_inicial . "' and '" . $fecha_final . "' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
                //Titulo, entidad, vivienda y descripcion
              } elseif (($titulo !== "") && (!empty($entidad)) && ($vivienda !== "") && (!empty($descripcion)) && (empty($gasto)) && (empty($ingreso))) {
                queryTipo('Sumar cantidad de Titulo, entidad, vivienda, descripcion y fechas');
                $query = "Select {$query_total} from movimientos where titulo = '" . $titulo . "' and entidad like '%" . $entidad . "%' and vivienda = '" . $vivienda . "' and descripcion like '%" . $descripcion . "%' and fecha between '" . $fecha_inicial . "' and '" . $fecha_final . "' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
                $query_suma = "Select sum(cantidad) as cantidad from movimientos where titulo = '" . $titulo . "' and entidad like '%" . $entidad . "%' and vivienda = '" . $vivienda . "' and descripcion like '%" . $descripcion . "%' and fecha between '" . $fecha_inicial . "' and '" . $fecha_final . "' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
                //Titulo y gasto
              } elseif (($titulo !== "") && (empty($entidad)) && ($vivienda == "") && (empty($descripcion)) && (!empty($gasto)) && (empty($ingreso))) {
                queryTipo('Sumar cantidad de Titulo, gastos y fechas');
                $query = "Select {$query_total} from movimientos where titulo = '" . $titulo . "' and operacion = 'gasto' and fecha between '" . $fecha_inicial . "' and '" . $fecha_final . "' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
                $query_suma = "Select sum(cantidad) as cantidad from movimientos where titulo = '" . $titulo . "' and operacion = 'gasto' and fecha between '" . $fecha_inicial . "' and '" . $fecha_final . "' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
                //Titulo y ingreso
              } elseif (($titulo !== "") && (empty($entidad)) && ($vivienda == "") && (empty($descripcion)) && (empty($gasto)) && (!empty($ingreso))) {
                queryTipo('Sumar cantidad de Titulo, ingreso y fechas');
                $query = "Select {$query_total} from movimientos where titulo = '" . $titulo . "' and operacion = 'ingreso' and fecha between '" . $fecha_inicial . "' and '" . $fecha_final . "' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
                $query_suma = "Select sum(cantidad) as cantidad from movimientos where titulo = '" . $titulo . "' and operacion = 'ingreso' and fecha between '" . $fecha_inicial . "' and '" . $fecha_final . "' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
              } elseif (($titulo == "") && (!empty($entidad)) && ($vivienda !== "") && (empty($descripcion)) && (empty($gasto)) && (empty($ingreso))) {
                queryTipo('Sumar cantidad de entidad, vivienda y fechas');
                $query = "Select {$query_total} from movimientos where entidad like '%" . $entidad . "%' and vivienda = '" . $vivienda . "' and fecha between '" . $fecha_inicial . "' and '" . $fecha_final . "' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
                $query_suma = "Select sum(cantidad) as cantidad from movimientos where entidad like '%" . $entidad . "%' and vivienda = '" . $vivienda . "' and fecha between '" . $fecha_inicial . "' and '" . $fecha_final . "' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
                //entidad y descripcion
              } elseif (($titulo == "") && (!empty($entidad)) && ($vivienda == "") && (!empty($descripcion)) && (empty($gasto)) && (empty($ingreso))) {
                queryTipo('Sumar cantidad de entidad, descripción y fechas');
                $query = "Select {$query_total} from movimientos where entidad like '%" . $entidad . "%' and descripcion like '%" . $descripcion . "%' and fecha between '" . $fecha_inicial . "' and '" . $fecha_final . "' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
                $query_suma = "Select sum(cantidad) as cantidad from movimientos where entidad like '%" . $entidad . "%' and descripcion like '%" . $descripcion . "%' and fecha between '" . $fecha_inicial . "' and '" . $fecha_final . "' and fecha < now() order by fecha desc;";
              }
            }

            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            $result_suma = mysqli_query($conn, $query_suma);
            busqueda($result,$query);
            suma($result_suma);
          } //fin con suma

        } //Fin submit



        ?>

        <?php
        /** Para comprobar la busqueda en test */
        function queryTipo($tipo)
        {
          //echo $tipo;
        }

        function busqueda($result,$query) {

          require('../../conn/connection.php');
        ?>

          <div class="tablaSearchMovimientos">

            <center>
              <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Título</th>
                    <th>Entidad</th>
                    <th>Cantidad</th>
                    <th>Fecha</th>
                    <th>Operación</th>
                    <th>Documento</th>
                    <th>renta</th>
                    <th>Vivienda</th>
                    <th>Inquilino</th>
                    <th>Expirado</th>
                    <th>Extra</th>
                  </tr>
                  <?php


                  //$query="Select {$query_total} from movimientos where titulo like '".$palabra."' order by fecha desc;";

                  //$count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $extraTexto = '';                       
                                if ($row['extra'] == '1') { $extraTexto = 'Extra'; }
                                if ($row['extraPisos']== '1') { $extraTexto = 'Extra de Pisos'; }
                    $vivienda =  $row['vivienda'];
                    $inquilino = $row['inquilino'];


                  ?>
                    <tr bgcolor="<?php ColorBackGround($row['titulo']); ?>">


                      <td><?php echo $row['titulo']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['entidad']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['cantidad']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['fecha1']; ?></td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['operacion']; ?>
                      <td><?php if (empty($row['doc'])) {
                            echo 'No hay imagen </td>';
                          } else {
                          ?>
                          <a class="image-link" href='../../upload/<?php echo $row['doc']; ?>' target="_blank"><?php echo $row['doc']; ?></a>
                        <?php
                          } ?>
                      </td>
                      <td><?php echo $row['renta']; ?></td>
                      <td>
                        <?php
                        $queryVivienda = "SELECT * from viviendas where tabla_index = '" . $vivienda . "'";
                        $resultVivienda = mysqli_query($conn, $queryVivienda);
                        $rowVivienda = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultVivienda);
                        echo $rowVivienda['alias'];
                        ?> </td>

                      <td><?php $queryInquilino = "SELECT * from arrendatarios where tabla_index = '" . $inquilino . "'";
                          $resultInquilino  = mysqli_query($conn, $queryInquilino);
                          $rowInquilino  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultInquilino);
                          if (isset($rowInquilino['alias']))  echo $rowInquilino['alias'];  else echo " - "; ?> </td>                      
                      <td><?php echo $extraTexto;?></td>

                      <td><a href="edit.php?GetID=<?php echo $row['tabla_index']; ?>" target="_blank"><img src="../../../images/writing.png" alt="Editar Registro" title="Editar Registro"></td>
                      <td><a href="del_register.php?Del=<?php echo $row['tabla_index']; ?>&Page=search&sql=<?php echo $query; ?>" onclick="return eliminar()"><img src="../../../images/delete.png" alt="Borrar Registro" title="Borrar Registro"></td>
                     <!-- <td><a href="#" onclick="delRegister($row['tabla_index'])"><img src="../../../images/delete.png" alt="Borrar Registro" title="Borrar Registro"></td>-->
                      <td><a href="../../upload/<?php echo $row['doc']; ?>" download><img src="../../../images/download.png" alt="Bajar archivo" title="Bajar archivo"></td>
                    </tr>
                  <?php } //Fin Fetch Result 
                  ?>
                </tbody>

              </table>
            </center>
          </div>

        <?php  } 


        function suma($result_suma)
        {

          $row = $result_suma->fetch_assoc();
          echo '<div style="color:red;font-size: 30px;"> Total : ' . $row['cantidad'] . '</div>';
        }

        ?>
```

Comment: Algún case? agrupar las condicionales y hacer la query en base a grupos de ellas?

Comment: Hola Ochoa. Prácticamente, son todo condicionales que contiene una query que se envía a una función. No entiendo, disculpa, que quieres decir con "agrupar las condicionales y hacer la query en base a grupos de ellas?"

Comment: Pues eso, si hay varias condiciones que se cumplen, haces una query en base a ellas o puedes hacer una query base e ir agregando parámetros en base a los `IF`. Hace poco hubo un tema sobre querys que a base de `IF` tenia varios filtros, veré si la busco para que tal vez puedas hacerte una idea.

Comment: Primero que nada tu pregunta esta basada en opiniones puden haber un mundo de formas de hacer lo que sugieres, el problema es que ese tipo de preguntas no son bien recibidas en su lugar te sugieron utilizar el sitio: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ en el cual con un ejemplo minimo reproducible te podran apoyar a mejorar tu codigo con las practicas que buscas...

Comment: este trabajo requiere un bounty, para el heroe que se atreba  a optimizar este codigo.

Comment: Jajaja, en eso estoy y solo he puesto una parte. Igualmente vamos a darlo por respondido. Muchas gracias a todos